# maps V2 and setRetainInstace(true) - is it leaking?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps, android-maps-v2, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Im using new maps v2 for Android.
I have been trying to save its state on orientation change. I thought about simply putting

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

in

```
onCreate()
```

method of my `SupportMapFragment` class

My tests were very positive, all works as it should. Then I run MAT analyzer and see that after a rotation two or more of my `MainActivity` instances are alive. Which is a RED FLAG. So I tested even more.

I've tested a scenario with my Custom Map Fragment.
I've tested a scenario with out of the box `SupportMapFragment`

Both scenarios are leaking `MainActivity` and give same results when I do in MAT :
Right click on `MainActivity` -> List Object -> with incoming references 
Right click "leaking" `MainActivity` -> Path to GC roots -> excluding weak references

[image]

How can I avoid leaking `MainActivity` while using `SupportMapFragment` with `setRetainInstance(true)` ?

Comment: There seems to be general memory leak issues: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766

Comment: Thanks Mark. As for today this bug has status of "FixedNotReleased"